# Skype 4.2.0.11 Crashes on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit During Video Call After Receiving IM

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, 64-bit, video, skype

Having an issue with Skype crashing while in a video call when anyone sends me an IM. I can have a Skype video call without any problems for any duration just as long as I don't receive any IM's during the duration of my video call. The moment that I receive an IM, Skype is guaranteed to crash within 1 or 2 seconds.

Searched this site along with others, contacted Skype, but I still can't get it to work properly.

Basic Computer info:

Memory: 7.7 GiB

Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz × 8

Graphics: Nvidia GeForce GT520M

OS Type: 64-bit

Disk: 27.1 GB

My video card actually doesn't come up under System Details, finding drivers for that has become a story in itself.

Hope someone out there knows what's up and can help me out! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you still have the problem, you should try this one:
http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/4-2-0-11-1-for-linux-crashes-when-answering-calls/td-p/1655001 - worked for me

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.